# ValueError: One input key expected got ['text_one', 'text_two'] in LangChain with memory and multiple inputs

Tags: python, langchain

I'm trying to run a chain in LangChain with memory and multiple inputs. The closest error I could find was was posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76765757/langchain-valueerror-one-input-key-expected-got-input-chat-history-lines), but in that one, they are passing only one input.

Here is the setup:

```py
from langchain.llms import OpenAI
from langchain.chains import LLMChain
from langchain.prompts import PromptTemplate
from langchain.memory import ConversationBufferMemory

llm = OpenAI(
    model="text-davinci-003",
    openai_api_key=environment_values["OPEN_AI_KEY"], # Used dotenv to store API key
    temperature=0.9,
    client="",
)

memory = ConversationBufferMemory(memory_key="chat_history")

prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=[
        "text_one",
        "text_two",
        "chat_history"
    ],
    template=(
        """You are an AI talking to a huamn. Here is the chat
        history so far:

        {chat_history}

        Here is some more text:

        {text_one}

        and here is a even more text:

        {text_two}
        """
    )
)

chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    memory=memory,
    verbose=False
)
```

When I run

```py
output = chain.predict(
    text_one="Hello",
    text_two="World"
)
```

I get `ValueError: One input key expected got ['text_one', 'text_two']`

I've looked at [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76199653/valueerror-run-not-supported-when-there-is-not-exactly-one-input-key-got-q), which suggests to try:

```py
output = chain(
    inputs={
        "text_one" : "Hello",
        "text_two" : "World"
    }
)
```

which gives the exact same error. In the spirit of trying different things, I've also tried:

```py
output = chain.predict( # Also tried .run() here
    inputs={
        "text_one" : "Hello",
        "text_two" : "World"
    }
)
```

which gives `Missing some input keys: {'text_one', 'text_two'}`.

I've also looked at [this issue on the langchain GitHub](https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/8710), which suggests to do pass the `llm` into memory, i.e.

```py
# Everything the same except...
memory = ConversationBufferMemory(llm=llm, memory_key="chat_history") # Note the llm here
```

and I still get the same error. If someone knows a way around this error, please let me know. Thank-you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While drafting this question, I came across the answer.

When defining the `memory` variable, pass an `input_key="human_input"` and make sure each prompt has a `human_input` defined.

```py
memory=ConversationBufferMemory(
    memory_key="chat_history",
    input_key="human_input"
)
```

Then, in each prompt, make sure there is a `human_input` input.

```py
prompt = PromptTemplate(
    input_variables=[
        "text_one",
        "text_two",
        "chat_history",
        "human_input", # Even if it's blank

    ],
    template=(
        """You are an AI talking to a huamn. Here is the chat
        history so far:

        {chat_history}

        Here is some more text:

        {text_one}

        and here is a even more text:

        {text_two}

        {human_input}
        """
    )
)
```

Then, build your chain:

```py
chain = LLMChain(
    llm=llm,
    prompt=prompt,
    memory=memory, # Contains the input_key
    verbose=False
)
```

And then run it as:

```py
output = chain.predict(
    human_input="", # or whatever you want
    text_one="Hello",
    text_two="World"
)
print(output)
# On my machine, it outputs: '\nAI: Hi there! How can I help you?'
```

Comment: You'd better deliver some real user input to `human_input`, otherwise, it will only save empty to memory.

Comment: What sort of arcane knowledge is this? Why would it fail, even though all variables are provided? Nowhere in the docs does it say you need to include a blank `human_input`. Why do you think this is? Anyway, thank you for figuring it out.